# A-frame gltf could not found

Tags: augmented-reality, aframe, gltf, ar.js

my code is like this
[my full coding screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/laNFX.jpg)

```
<a-scene  embedded arjs='sourceType: webcam; debugUIEnabled: false;'>
       <a-gltf-model src="/website/models/pixel_art_mouse_cursor/scene.gltf" position='0 0 -8' scale='0.5 0.5 0.5'>
       </a-gltf-model>
</a-scene>
```

I download this gltf model here
https://sketchfab.com/3d-models/pixel-art-mouse-cursor-7cc4bad913b74b48b86d8d05e2785b9c
and my console could not load it
[error screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R4XG8.jpg)

Thanks

Comment: Make sure you are using a local server to serve the files. Browsers don't have access to the local file system https://aframe.io/docs/1.0.0/introduction/faq.html#why-does-my-asset-e-g-image-video-model-not-load

Answer (score 0):

Try using global URL, like this:

```
<a-gltf-model src="https://rawgit.com/KhronosGroup/glTF-Sample-Models/master/2.0/DamagedHelmet/glTF/DamagedHelmet.gltf"></a-gltf-model>
```